# Changing parent div elementHeight when clicked on another parent child

Tags: jquery, toggle, parent-child, parent, toggleclass

I need some help and I can't figure this out.

Below are 2 parent divs (.fourPackCont) and in each div there are 4 div with 4 images (.eventItem).

Right now div.venueDropdown is hidden. When the image is clicked, it becomes visible and the venue information slidesDown. When you click on that same image, the venue information slidesUp and the fourPackCont goes back to it's normal height.

My problem is that if I click on the 1st image of the 1st parent div, and then click on say the 2nd image of the 2nd parent div, the div of the 1st image slides Up but the parent div still shows a big huge gap vs going back to its original size.

```
<div class="fourPackCont">
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="fourPackCont">
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-index="0" data-taxonomy="los-angeles-ca" class="eventItem">
      <div style="background-image:url();" class="eventImg"></div>
         <div class="venueName">The Nice Guy</div>
         <div class="venueCity">Los Angeles, CA</div>
         <div class="contArrow"></div>
         <div class="venueDropdown"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the js:

```
    function OpenCloseItem(that){
        var parent = jQuery(that).closest(".eventItem");
        var target = parent.find('.venueDropdown');
        var targetArrow = parent.find('.contArrow');
        var heightElement;
        var specialCase;
        if(responsiveLevel == 0){
            heightElement = parent.closest(".fourPackCont");
            specialCase = false;
        }else if(responsiveLevel == 1){
            if(parseInt(parent.attr("data-index")) > 1){
                heightElement = parent.closest(".fourPackCont");
                specialCase = true;
            }else if(parseInt(parent.attr("data-index")) <= 1){
                heightElement = parent.closest(".fourPackCont").find(".dualPackClear");
                specialCase = false;
            }
        }else if(responsiveLevel == 2){
            heightElement = parent;
            specialCase = false;
        }

        var elementH ;
        var dropdownH ;
        if(target.hasClass('active') && targetArrow.hasClass('active')){
            target.toggleClass('active');
            target.slideUp('fast');   
            targetArrow.toggleClass('active');
            targetArrow.slideUp('fast');   
            elementH = parent.height();
            dropdownH = target.height();
            if(responsiveLevel == 1){
                if(!specialCase){
                    heightElement.animate({height:"0px"},'slow');
                }else{
                    heightElement.animate({height:elementH+elementH+"px"},'slow');
                } 
            }else{
                heightElement.css("height","auto");  
            }

        }else{
            elementH = parent.height();
            dropdownH = target.height();
            if(responsiveLevel == 1){
                if(!specialCase){
                    heightElement.animate({height:dropdownH+20+"px"},'slow');
                }else{
                    heightElement.animate({height:elementH+elementH+dropdownH+20+"px"},'slow');
                }
            }else{
                heightElement.animate({height:elementH+dropdownH+20+"px"},'slow');
            }

            jQuery(".venueDropdown.active").hide();
            jQuery(".venueDropdown.active").toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(".contArrow.active").hide();
            jQuery(".contArrow.active").toggleClass("active")
            target.toggleClass('active');
            target.slideDown('slow');
            targetArrow.toggleClass('active');
            targetArrow.slideDown('slow');
        }
    }

    jQuery(".eventItem .eventImg").on("click", function(){
        OpenCloseItem(jQuery(this));
    })
    jQuery(".closeDrop .close").on("click",function(){
        OpenCloseItem(jQuery(this));
    })
```

This script only works if I click on the image itself or the close button but not when I click on another image in a different parent div.

Comment: Here's a start. Please define `responsiveLevel` to fix the error and see if you can get a demo working. http://jsfiddle.net/206sbp0u/

Comment: @isherwood I got it to kind of work. Just the images aren't showing up. But if you click on say the a venue in the middle and the click on the first one, you'll see that big gap. The gap only closes if you click on that venue name again.